# How do I see Meteor logs when the server is being run by another user?

Tags: meteor, nitrousio

I'm currently using Nitrous.io for Meteor pair programming, but the server logs only show up for the user who is running the server. I tried `meteor logs` but it didn't work. Is there a log file that I can monitor with `tail`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a terminal multiplexer like Tmux, that way you guys can share the same terminal window.

We have some information on Tmux here:

http://help.nitrous.io/faq-disconnect/

Answer (score 2):

You can ask your buddy to output the log to a shared folder, dirty and simple solution. You can also use some cloud based log system. Check this article about this topic by Arunoda: [Link](https://meteorhacks.com/logging-support-for-meteor.html)

Answer (score 2):

What if you logged to a collection and this collection was visible to the developers only?